# How to cast `Array` type to `[]` or to `List`?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum));
```

Which returns data of type `Array`. I am not comfortable with it, and therefore I want to convert it to a common normal array `T[]` or `List<T>`. How can I do that?

P.S. I did **not** find any `ToList` or `ToArray` function.

Comment: Just cast: `var array = (SomeEnum[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum))`;

Answer (score 0):

convertAll() method.
Var getvalue=[Your enum value];
`Array.ConvertAll(getvalue, element => element.ToString());`
This will convet your enum array to String Array. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: The answer provided in the comments by Jon Skeet is much more simpler and does what needed